# Pass value to the annotations

Tags: java

I want to pass the values to the annotation. Example:

```
@Feature(someVaribleName)
```

If `someVaribleName` is `final` then things are working fine. So this is working fine:

```
private final String someVaribleName = "test";
@Feature(someVaribleName)
public void testMethod()
{
}
```

But I want to pass additional information, that I will be coming to know in run-time only, so changing `someVaribleName` is not possible.

Are there any ways to pass the run-time value to the annotations in java?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is via code injection e.g. using [Instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).

However a simpler solution is to have the framework using the Annotation support reflection e.g.

```
@Feature("someVaribleName")
```

The framework would obtain the variable your specify `someVaribleName` from the object.

Or you could call a method

```
@Feature("getSomeName")
```

and the framework would need to call the method you configured i.e. `getSomeName`

Comment: How to do this in Instrumentation?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly. Annotations are compiled by java compiler and written into byte code of annotated class.

I can suggest you the following solution. You can define interface that declares method that returns value of specified type. Then you can implement this interface as you want and annotate method with annotation that refers to this implementation.

```
interface Provider<T> {
    T getValue();
}

@interface FeatureProvider {
   Class<? extends Provider> value();
}

class SomeProviderImpl implements Provider<Integer> {
    // the implementation can be as complicated as you want. 
    Integer getValue() { return 123; }
}
```

Now here is how you can use it:

```
@FeatureProvider(SomeProviderImpl.class)
public void testMethod() {}
```

Comment: SomeProviderImpl.class gives me the value?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Take a look on Peter's answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Basically you cannot pass a variable to the annotation because they are processed during compile time. However the annotation library can implement a placeholders approach - for example you pass `#{myVariable}` as a value and during runtime the annotation library can do the job needed to take the value behind the placeholder.